# Java using SHA1

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, sha1

I try to implement a SHA1 decoder but i can't find something usefull on internet. Can anyone help me find information on how I can implement an SHA1 decryption. I want to transform the encrypted data to Strings.

Comment: SHA1 is not encryption, therefore there is no decryption of SHA1.

Comment: Another thing you should be aware of: hash algorithms operate on *byte arrays*, not *Strings*. The server side you mentioned will give you the hash of some string that's encoded into a byte array using a specific *character set*, and if your input is Strings, you'll have to encode them using the same *character set*. Which one that is is part of the protocol between where you're receiving the SHA-1 hash from and your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I try to implement a SHA1 decoder but i can't find something useful on internet.

[SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is a [*hash function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). It's one-way: you hash the data, and get a hash. If you hash the same data, you'll get the hash; if you hash different data, you'll "almost certainly" get a different hash.

If you could "decrypt" it, it wouldn't be doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

If you figure out how to crack sha1 props to you. I think the government may be able to do it but you would be hard pressed to find a public library that has a smart algorithm that doesnt take a great deal of resources to crack.

[they claim they can crack it and decrypt it, I doubt it works](http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/sha1-decrypt.aspx)
[another source that claims they can decrypt it, i doubt their code is publicly available though](http://crackstation.net/)

Is there a specific reason you are trying to decrypt it, maybe there is a flaw in your design or another way to solve your problem?

heres a neat diaolog about the progression of [sha1](http://johans.livejournal.com/3834.html)

Comment: Actually server side provides me the password. The password is encrypted with SHA1 algorithm.

Comment: so you want to decrypt your passwords server-side to see the plaintext version of it from users?

Comment: @AlexDowining If you need to compare them, what you need to do is "encrypt" the plaintext password you have and compare the hashed versions.

Comment: @AlexDowining That said, in an ideal world, you wouldn't store plaintext passwords. The fact that the last year had at least one major website leak some of their password database on a monthly basis should illustrate why that's a bad idea.

Comment: @BobSinclar The first site you link only seems to look up hashes in a database

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the password behind a SHA1 hash, put the Hash on google.
If the password is common, and the hash is not 'SALTED', you have a chance to get the password.

Else read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions are designed to  be one-way. So you can't simply calculate the input from the output. Doing this is called a pre-image attack. If the message itself can't be guessed, such an attack requires around 2^159 attempts, which is infeasible.

The best way to reverse SHA-1 is to guess the input. For typical user passwords this attack succeeds quite often, since the password isn't complex enough. For example a typical GPU will be able to try >100mio passwords per second.

This is why we don't use plain SHA-1 for password hashing. We use deliberately slow schemes, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt with sufficient work-factor.